Seeking Evaluated Datasets for Timefold Employee Scheduling Performance
We are currently using Timefold for employee scheduling and are looking to better understand performance characteristics.
Could you please share any sample datasets (if you have them) that have been evaluated in terms of time taken and system performance across various algorithms? We would greatly appreciate this data for our learning.
I noticed in the Optimization Algorithms Overview  that such information may have been captured. Any insights or resources you could provide would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
